# VoIP NAT to connect to companies of the same ip address range together

Tags: networking, routing, nat, voip, troubleshooting

I am currently using packet tracer to configure the network for Company A. I have configured DHCP and telephony service successfully but the problem I'm facing is when company A tries to contact Company B. Since both are in the same network range I have to NAT the traffic inside and outside with an ACL as well. i have provided a picture of the topology with the IP addressing. I have tried to do some natting using the commands:

```
ip nat outside
...
ip nat inside source list 1 pool VOIP overload
..
access list 1 permit any
```

Network scheme:

[image: Network scheme]

Company B was already configured and is locked, but when I try to call from Company B the packets stop at the gateway (GW_CA) in Company A. So the problem has to be at GW_CA.

Comment: Can you post your NAT configurations for both sides?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think you'll get this working with SIP. Not with a single PBX at least. You might get somewhere using a PBX inside each network and some sort of inter-site bridge between the PBXs. If it were me, I'd bite the bullet and renumber the LAN at one site or the other.